# Find first non-empty value amongst the multiple different properties from json array

Tags: json, transform, jolt

In JSON input I get some times array and some times single object without array tag in json. How to transform the JSON using Jolt transformation expecting both scenarios as a input

**JSON without array** :

```json
{
  "eventMetadata": {
    "eventType": "Insert",
    "baseObjectUid": "BASE_OBJECT",
    "orsId": "orcl-TCR_HUB",
    "triggerUid": "MESSAGE_QUEUE_RULE",
    "messageId": "300894188",
    "messageDate": "2023-08-30T23:54:32.335Z"
  },
  "insertEvent": {
    "systemDetails":{
      "systems":{
        "sourceSystemName": "R12"
      }
    },
    "sourceKey": "XXXXX",
    "eventDate": "2023-08-30T23:54:32.335Z",
    "rowid": "9800029",
    "xrefKey": {
      "systemName": "",
      "sourceKey": "XXXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

From Above Json find first non empty value amongst the `insertEvent.systemDetails.systems.sourceSystemName` and `insertEvent.xrefKey.systemName`

**Expected JSON first non empty non null**  :

```json
{
  "systemName": "R12",
}
```

**JSON with array** :

```json
{
  "eventMetadata": {
    "eventType": "Insert",
    "baseObjectUid": "BASE_OBJECT",
    "orsId": "orcl-TCR_HUB",
    "triggerUid": "MESSAGE_QUEUE_RULE",
    "messageId": "300894188",
    "messageDate": "2023-08-30T23:54:32.335Z"
  },
  "insertEvent": [
    {
      "systemDetails":{
      "systems":{
        "sourceSystemName": ""
      }
    }
      "sourceKey": "XXXXX",
      "eventDate": "2023-08-30T23:54:32.335Z",
      "rowid": "9800029",
      "xrefKey": {
        "systemName": "",
        "sourceKey": "XXXXX"
      }
    },
    {
      "systemDetails":{
      "systems":{
        "sourceSystemName": "R12"
      }
    }
      "sourceKey": "XXXXX",
      "eventDate": "2023-08-30T23:54:32.335Z",
      "rowid": "9800029",
      "xrefKey": {
        "systemName": "",
        "sourceKey": "XXXXX"
      }
    },
    {
      "systemDetails":{
      "systems":{
        "sourceSystemName": "Y12"
      }
    }
      "sourceKey": "XXXXX",
      "eventDate": "2023-08-30T23:54:32.335Z",
      "rowid": "9800029",
      "xrefKey": {
        "systemName": "Y12",
        "sourceKey": "XXXXX"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output JSON first not empty non null value** :

From Above Json find first non empty value amongst the `insertEvent.systemDetails.systems.sourceSystemName` and `insertEvent.xrefKey.systemName`

```json
{
  "systemName": "R12"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider adding indexes by **`"*"`** wildcard for the case with array and ignore it for the non-array case within a shift transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@insertEvent": {
        "*": { // the indexes of the "insertEvent" array
          "@systemDetails.systems.sourceSystemName": { // the conditional for the S/systemName values starts here
            "": "", // blank values
            "*": { // values with length > 0
              "$": "systemName" // current key values which are the values inherited from the upper node
            }
          },
          "@xrefKey.systemName": {
            "": "",
            "*": {
              "$": "systemName"
            }
          }
        },
        "@systemDetails.systems.sourceSystemName": {
          "": "",
          "*": {
            "$": "systemName[]"
          }
        },
        "@xrefKey.systemName": {
          "": "",
          "*": {
            "$": "systemName[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // in order to pick the first component from the array or object
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "0": "&1"
      },
      "0": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi @Prasad S Deshpande , were you able to check this out ?